Replace a 1-15P or 5-15P connector with 6-15P for 120-240v compatible device?
I have a 220v bandsaw (Laguna 14|BX) that features an accessory outlet with a 220v NEMA 6-15 receptacle. Alas, the only work light I’ve found with that spec is, surprise, Laguna’s $150 one.
There are plenty of affordable work lights out there that are rated at 120-240v, which is common for us/euro cross-compatibility with just a plug adapter. (You can take most US devices you run on household 110v to Europe and plug them into their 220v wall sockets with just a prong adapter, no voltage converter required.) There’s even a 5-15 to 6-15 adapter available:
https://www.amazon.com/PLIS-110V-120V-220V-Adapter/dp/B07YG8971Q?th=1
However, most of the work lights have ungrounded 1-15 (2-prong) plugs, not grounded 5-15 (3-prong) plugs like this adapter supports. In the 110v world, we plug 2-prong 1-15P devices into 3-prong 5-15R outlets all day long. But I don’t know if I can safely make the same assumption in the 220v world.
(FWIW, rather than go with an adapter like the one above, I would probably want to just cut and replace the 1-15P with a 6-16P hardwired plug for stability.)
If your first impulse is to warn against plugging something with a 110v plug into a 220v receptacle, let me repeat and emphasize: the lights I’m looking at have a rating of 120-240v, so the power supplies should be built for the current. I’m more worried about any trickiness in wiring the connectors, or if the whole thing is unfeasible or unsafe because of the things that are unknown unknowns for me with my paltry electrical knowledge.
Thanks!

For stuff like 240v lights/heaters it should be okay.  The problem happens when plugging in a device that requires both 240v and 120v(dryers) since they require a neutral wire also to get 120v, instead of just two hots(plus ground) found in 6-15(any 6-X plug)

You also want to use 6-15 receptacles/plugs to future proof idiots plugging 120v devices in a 5-15 receptacle.

Although a doubling of the voltage (from 110V to 220V) sounds like a lot, it doesn't actually have that much influence on how to make a safe appliance. On this side of the pond, in a primarily 240V world, we also don't think twice about plugging a two-prong appliance (designed to work without ground) into a socket that does provide ground.

Is the saw hardwired or plug-in?
